# SQL Cluster (Always On) - Database table replication

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, clustering

I have the following scenario at this moment.
Two old sql servers - they have setup some kind of publisher subscriber replication from one database to another but only some of the tables at a 12 hour time span.

I have built and Always On cluster , where I have created one listener but I have three availability groups, one for each database.
I would like to know how could I implement that sort of replication from one database to another and keep the SQL always On .

Techincal Details - I have WS2K19 Standrad edition with SQL 2017 Standrad edition latest CU , and only two nodes in the SQL cluster and a witness disk to provide qvorum.
SQLNODE1
SQLNODE2

Could maybe someone propose or share a solution ? I want to keep the SQL always on for HA/DR as the two vm's are in different locations .

Comment: Hi,

Your question is not super clear. 

You only have 1 listener for 3 AG group ? Which one have the listener configured ? How do you access the other 2 ? 

Replication from one database to another... So right now, you have 3 databases on each node of your AG right ? And you want to replicate from one of the DB to another one (on the same node). This is only to be able to see the data as it was 12 hours ago is that correct ?

If it is, do you need that 12 hours behind DB to be in AG as well ?

Comment: Hello at this moment I have a configuration with publisher subscriber thing. 1 server in DMZ with one data base , and internal Two servers. the two servers from internal lan have each one database , from DMZ i have specific tables with columns that are replicated in LAN. I want to bring all the databases in LAN and have two nodes primary and secondary . with windows server 2017, I can make three availability groups one for each database . and a dummy database that keeps the listener which is an AD object ofc.

Comment: To add on to Dominique, usually one choose **Replication** when they're not doing **AlwaysOn Availability Groups** but when one is doing on **AlwaysOn** then they normally synchronize the data via **Availability Groups**. Are you saying you want to do both **Replication** and **AlwaysOn Availability Groups**, and why?

Comment: the question is how can I keep those replications, in such a way that i can have a cluster of sql. as far as i know if i configure anything it's in the master.db on the primary , in case of a failover ....the jobs/replications won't work. is there a solution ? i don't necessarly need publisher subscriber stuff. as long as I can keep all the databases updated . and no it's not necessarly to have the 12 hours behind. it can be synchronized

Comment: The three databases serve different applications, but they need info from one database in another database. basically that's why I even have three databases, so in that case app number 1 with DMZ which has a website , database 2 that has an internal app , and database three with another internal app. they have some common tables and columns that need to be updated if possible synchronous if not at least 12 hour or 6 hour behind

Comment: update : I created always on cluster with two nodes . did all the availability groups - managed to create a replica with local publication of a table and content of the table and also subscriber. same Listener and everything works great. the only issue is, when I trigger a failover - even though I have been working from the listener, the replication won't work as I have seen the server always takes the primary no matter what I do. I am thinking of how to create the publication and subscription in a way if a failover occurs the replication would work in the other instance too .

Comment: I would check for read_scale availability group instead of using replication in your case.
That would allow you to sync your 3 DBs on 3 nodes (that doesn't need to be in a cluster which will ease the futur support)